# Interactive console on Pydev - Eclipse for Tensorflow

Tags: eclipse, tensorflow, pydev

I have installed Tensorflow with Virtualenv in my Linux Mint 18.3 Xfce. 
I have Pydev for Eclipse Neon and I have added a new python interpreter pointing to "bin/python" executable inside tensorflow virtualenv folder.
I am able to execute programs by selecting this interpreter, but when I open the interactive console and select the interpreter for tensorflow I get an error:

Error initializing console.
Unexpected error connecting to console.
Failed to receive suitable Hello response from pydevconsole. Last msg received: Console already exited with value: 1 while waiting for an answer.

I can't understand why this happens. For example I tried another IDE called Pyzo, configured the tensorflow interpreter and the interactive shell run without any problems.

Anyone has experienced the same issue?

Comment: Which PyDev version are you using?

Comment: PyDev version is 6.2.0.201711281614